# Running Windows 2008 VPS with Hyper-V on UltimaHosts.Net Server

Tags: windows-server-2008

I've got an interesting issue running Active Directories within a [Windows 2008 VPS R2 Hyper-V](http://www.ultimahosts.net/windows/2008/vps) on an UltimaHosts.net server. Basically the install fails half way through with the error being that I don't have enough permission to complete the task. Looked up the KB but found no help there. Any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Are you logged in as local administrator?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (since you didn't post an error code) but my first suspect would be that you either chose their DNS server or didn't set that server up as one first.  The task that it can't complete would be creating the SRV records in DNS.  Install that server with the DNS server role first for the domain that you own (or use a pseudo-domain for your TLD like mydomain.internal) then install active directory and when asked point it toward your new DNS server.